# Scraping only craigslist ads posted today

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

Hello guys I'm making a Scrapy spider that only scrapes the ads which are posted today. But I think my code has a problem, please help me. And it is also supposed to scrape the email addresses from ads but it doesn't scrape the emails. Titles, urls and ad locations are scraped just fine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date,timedelta

options = {

    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 60,
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 10000,
    'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.24 
     (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24",
    'SW_SAVE_BUFFER': 30,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
}    

current_date = "datetime.today().strftime('%b %d')"  

class adscrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'ad-scrapper'
allowed_domains = ['www.craigslist.org']
start_urls = ['https://phoenix.craigslist.org/']

def parse(self, response):
    ad = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')

    for ad in ad-scrapper:
        title = ad.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
        address = ad.xpath('span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-
    hood"]/text()').extract_first("")[2:-1]
        relative_url = ad.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)

        if current_date == datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d').strftime('%b 
    %d'):
            yield{'URL':absolute_url, 'Title':title, 'Address':address, 
   'Email':email}

        else:
            print('there was no ad posted yesterday!')
```

Comment: why is `current_date` quoted?

Comment: I don't see an assignment to `date`.

Comment: i have just started learning scrapy, can you please tell in a bit more detail, where to make changes

Comment: Hey @sarainam ..  Which ads specifically?? like... all o the sections?? or ...  also.... just at first glance your initial request..."start_url"... and you set an xpath thats not a acual node so im very confused how you eve getting past the initial parse lol

Comment: im here for ya ...just please explain a litttle more in detail what you intent is... get emails and contact info I got that but again... like.. all sections.. or just or rent or sale lol